# sharing ios development between developer and non-developer

Tags: ios, project, share, ipa

I'm about to make an individual iOS dev account, but I would like to share my work with a colleague or two for input that do not have an account (they have Xcode).  They will look at the code maybe a bit, but mainly to test the app itself and provide feedback for me.  Currently I don't have an account and what I have done is take a screencast of the app in the simulator and send the screencast.  Obviously not ideal.  So what are my options to share my progress on a daily basis?  I think just to have them run in the simulator on their end is fine, until the app is almost complete then maybe on their phone would be good too.  Thanks,

rc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) look at testflight (testflightapp.com) - it's a site which allows you to email ad hoc builds of an app to testers.

B) put your code into version control and give them access. (ie GitHub.com) then they can build it themselves with Xcode onto their devices.

I'd go with A, it gives you more control and the potential for fewer support questions :)

I'm not sure why you would want non-developers looking at your code but I'd that's really needed, option B :)

Answer (score 1):

The type of developer account you get and your ability to share your code are two unrelated issues. Unless you want your colleagues to be able to build your code and install it on test devices, they don't need developer program subscriptions. You can share your code with them in whatever way suits you (give them read access to your version control system), and you can build test versions that they can install on their devices. The only thing they won't be able to do is to build the app themselves for installation on a device.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.  The main thing is I can do some work and send it to my colleague and say hey take a look at this what do you think?  Yeah I don't need to send them the whole project, and they can install Xcode so just for them to run in the simulator is probably enough most of the time.  I'll try all of the suggestions here thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the main purpose is for testing, then get an enterprise certificate, sign the app with it and send the ipa file. They will install it and test the app.